# Selenium webdriver xpath randomly not recognized

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When running the code appears that the XPath for the `Aprobă` button isn't recognized and doesn't click on it even if when I inspect the element on the site the XPath seems to find the correct button.

The error is:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(.,'')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'js-answer-element')]//span[@class='sg-icon-as-button__hole']"}

My method `approveAnswerByUsername(String username)` should check if the answer has been approved or not. An approved answer is recognized by the 3 buttons near the username and the green circle under it. 
The user can be the first one that answers, the second one or the only one. That's why I used "ancestor" in the XPath.

In some cases, the circles have been seen(even in the precedent case it was) and in others not. The same with the button `"Aprobă"`.

The code below should do the following:
1. connect to the www.brainly.ro and login with the credentials
2. open the window of the user Lola1511
3. open all the answered questions and check if it has been approved or not. If isn't approved, then approve it.

Below I post my entire code (the link to the site and the credentials are all there)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class classTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        try {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\sanduc\\Desktop\\Selenium\\Kits\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void log_in() {

        try {
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//div[@class='sg-content-box__actions']/nav[@class='brn-hero__navigation']/a[1]"))
                    .click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@action='/login?entry=2&return=/']/div[2]/input"))
                    .sendKeys("my_emal@mail.com");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@action='/login?entry=2&return=/']/div[3]/input"))
                    .sendKeys("my_password");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.get("");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void click_pages() {
        try {
            int index_while = 1;

            while (true) {
                driver.get("" + index_while);
                List<WebElement> demovar = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='task-content']/a"));
                System.out.println(demovar.size());
                System.out.println("+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+");
                System.out.println("Current page: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
                System.out.println("+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+");

                ArrayList<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>(); // List for
                                                                    // storing
                                                                    // all href
                                                                    // values
                                                                    // for 'a'
                                                                    // tag

                for (WebElement var : demovar) {
                    System.out.println(var.getText()); // used to get text
                                                        // present between the
                                                        // anchor tags
                    System.out.println(var.getAttribute("href"));
                    hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href"));
                    System.out.println("*************************************");
                }

                // Navigating to each link
                int i = 0;
                for (String href : hrefs) {
                    driver.navigate().to(href);
                    System.out.println((++i) + ": navigated to URL with href: " + href);
                    approveAnswerByUsername("Lola1511");
                    Thread.sleep(3000); // To check if the navigation is
                                        // happening properly.
                    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

                }
                index_while++;
                if (demovar.size() < 5) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void approveAnswerByUsername(String username) {
        try {

            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + username
                        + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'js-answer-element')]//span[@class='sg-icon-as-button__hole']")).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("The homework " + driver.getCurrentUrl() + " has ALREADY been approved");

            } else {

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'" + username
                        + "')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'js-answer-element')]//div[contains(@class,'js-approve-button-text')][contains(.,'Aprobă')]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.navigate().refresh();
                System.out.println("The homework " + driver.getCurrentUrl() + " has been approved NOW");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium xpath causes randomly errors in selemium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506371/selenium-xpath-causes-randomly-errors-in-selemium)

Comment: it's also mine that question. It's not a duplicate because i changed the code and the logic for the problematic method.

Comment: You should avoid using real credential in the code published on public websites.

Comment: isn't real. It's a test user.

Comment: Maybe you should use Thread.sleep(); before clicking

Comment: just did. still the same problem.

Comment: @ctina Can you update the exact business case which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: @DebanjanB i just did.

Comment: @ctina Can't proceed further as `my_emal@brainly.com/my_password` is not a valid pair of credentials. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB someone edited my question and has deleted those. Please try with: username: cristina-maria.sandu@brainly.com ; psw: Ctina.maria31. Thanks

Comment: One question, what are you trying to do here `driver.navigate().to(href);`?

Comment: to access each link from the list of five (the number of answers from each page)

Comment: 3/4 th Done :) `1. connect to the www.brainly.ro and login with the credentials 2. open the window of the user Lola1511 3. open all the answered questions`

Comment: the approve part is the most problematic :(

Comment: Nopes :) Actually you made the logic too much complicated ;) I have reduced a lot many lines from your code

Comment: @DebanjanB did you manage to find out what's the problem with that xpath?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't check the code due to time limitations but I would suggest a different approach for using selectors.

**Use ID selectors or name selectors in the webpage instead of xpaths.**

ID selectors are the best and fastest way for selecting elements. Xpaths are slower and sometimes unreliable.

My advice would be to try ID and name selectors and use xpath only if both are not found.

Comment: i can't (or at least i don't know how) because i need to find  the answer of a specific user (that can be the first, the second or the only one) and after that to locate the action buttons near his usermane.